# Want UITextView to not userInteract but recognize link clicks

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I placed UITextView on a UITableViewCell subclass, and **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** gets called only when i tap on the cell *outside* of UITextView, however tap on link inside opens Safari.

How can i process click inside UITextView not assuming tap on link?

P.S. Setting

```
myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

looks fine, but links are not detected

Answer (score 2):

No need to disable user interaction. Instead, make the textView non-editable:

```
myTextView.editable = NO;
```

Comment: While that does it, it sure feels like a UITextView bug. What's the ability to edit got to do with data detection? Nothing.